# Restore files overwritten from image restoration?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, restore, system-restore, file-recovery

So I had a problem with my Windows 7 install and decided to restore a month old image to fix it since nothing else was working. I was able to access the hard drive so I backed up my main folder and restored the image.

Immediately after reboot I realized I hadn't backed up my OneNote files, so I had just lost a month of notes (I'm a student).

Are there any tools that can help me restore these files or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you didn't have your notes synced to OneDrive. Look into switching that on for next time.

It is impossible to say whether your files are recoverable without looking. Recovery relies on the lost files not being overwritten by other files. If your hard drive was 100GB and you've only restored a 25GB image to it, there's a lower chance your files have been overwritten than if you restored a 50GB image to it.

It would be worth trying a tool like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva). If possible, boot up your computer on a different drive than the one you put the new image onto. This will reduce the chances of overwriting further files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'm currently on my Linux partition, I switched to it as soon as I realized what I'd done....I'll give this a try!